# Why tailwind css custom font doesnt work in my project?

Tags: css, fonts, tailwind-css

I would like to add custom fonts (Inter and Montserrat) with tailwindccs but have problem becouse when i open profject in live server font doesnt change

style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.button {
    @apply px-4 py-3 rounded-full text-sm text-center
}

.image-transform {
    @apply transition transform
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/**/*.{html,js}',
    './src/**/*.{html,js}',
    './node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js',
  ],
  mode: 'jit',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        beige: '#DCC1AB',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        inter: ['Inter', 'sans-serif'],
        montserrat: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require('tw-elements/dist/plugin.cjs')],
};
```

Where can be problem? I build css file after chenges and fonts doesnt change in project